# Display type alias for primitive types

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-front-end, custom-types

I have observed few pallets have type alias for primitive types for chain state.

For eg- Grandpa pallet has one storage **setIdSession** which shows type as **SetId** even though its primitive type is **u64**. [image]

How can i impl same for custom pallet? I have tried creating type alias like PoolId but it always shows primitive type why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a feature of PolkadotJS. It was pre-registered [here](https://vscode.dev/github.com/polkadot-js/docs/blob/a523a0157cd72b9c86350c17865fd97413782150/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen/src/interfaces/augment-types.ts#L575).

---

Type alias can't work here. But I'm wondering if `PoolId(u64)` works.

Comment: Thanks alot for replying. I have observed mutiple projects which had defined types alias for primitive types. Did they all registered there type? For eg - Automata ContextFree project have defined BridgeChainId which are primitive underneath. But i do not see BridgeChainId in types file you shared. 

Also, i tested with tuple struct it didn't work for me but then i tied with normal struct it works but don't you think its not logical to use struct for only a single member? What do you think is the most efficient way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Could you provide the link?

Comment: It looks like they also tweak the types. https://github.com/automata-network/automata

Comment: How i can too tweak types for my pallet?

Comment: It looks like all these projects have added there types here. Automata also defined BridgeChainId [Here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec/automata.ts)

Comment: Correct. But their README is outdated (that only works with `metadata version < v14`).